# Problems connecting collective member to controller for JMX

Tags: jmx, websphere-liberty, mbeans

I have a collective with one controller and two members. When I try to call an MBean in one of the members from the controller, I'm getting an MBean object in the response, and it looks correct, except that it doesn't actually contain any data for the values (in this case, it's for looking at threadpools).

When I look in the logs for both of my collective members, I am seeig the following error message at startup:

> [11/2/15 11:38:07:150 EST] 00000040
>   llective.member.internal.publisher.ServerManagementPublisher W
>   CWWKX8127W: Unable to publish the JMX endpoint information for this
>   server. This server's MBeans will not be able to be managed through
>   the collective. A configuration or other type of warning or error has
>   occurred. Check the previous warning or error messages for possible
>   corrective action.

The problem is, there are no other messages that give me any idea what the error is all about. Does anyone have any suggestions for a trace to turn on, or maybe have an idea of what night be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does the warning occur each time the member starts?  The warning indicates that at the time of publishing, the JMX endpoint is not setup. To confirm this is what you are seeing, on a member server (in the server.xml), enabling this trace will give clues if this is what is happening on your server:

<logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.collective.member.internal.publisher.MemberJMXEndpointImpl=all" />

Through this trace when the member starts you will be able to see if the JMX endpoint does not yet have its information at the time of publishing.  When it receives the information, you will see a beginning trace like this (in a normal case, this will occur before the publishing that is producing the warning):

`collective.member.internal.publisher.MemberJMXEndpointImpl > setJMXEndpointObject Entry`